# Issues with Ntsokrnl.exe

Tags: windows, process

I've been to use port 8092 to use some propriety software my company has made, but it seems the port is in use. Further tracking it down shows the PID of the process using the port as 4 (which as I understand is a System process in Windows 7 Professional SP1 (x64)). I'm running on an HP ZBook 15 laptop. Viewing the process in the task manager shows it as "System" with PID=4.

The image path name is "C:\Windows\System32\ntoskrnl.exe" and the description is NT Kernel & System. All efforts to kill this task have failed, as it is a system process (though I did get a BSOD crash when trying) According to this article, if this executable shows up as a process, it is a strong indicator of malware:

http://www.runscanner.net/lib/ntoskrnl.exe.html

I'd really like to avoid having to re-image this machine, as it is an involving process. I don't know if this was my fault or not. I've run a variety of anti-virus and spyware programs from safe mode but wasn't able to find anything. The process remains.

Comment: You've simply posted this question on the wrong website.  StackOverflow is for problems with *your* code.  Here you are having a problem with something on the system that's not your code.  Computer administration and maintenance questions usually find a home at SuperUser... although before asking there you really should think of a better title.  I suggest "Can I stop ntoskrnl.exe from locking my TCP port?"

Answer (score 1):

`ntoskrnl.exe` is the NT Kernel, you cannot kill it, and it is not malware. If the NT Kernel is using a network port, that most likely means that IIS is serving requests from that port (since HTTP.SYS runs in kernel context).

Comment: Is there a way I can change the port?  It seems like all my other coworkers have that port available for this software to run on except for me. Check out the article I posted (I just updated the post)  Is that wrong?  "You should never see ntoskrnl.exe running in the Task Manager. The presence of an instance of it in the task manager is a strong indicator of a malware infection."